# adding numbers in two different while loops

Tags: php, mysql

I am fetching data from database in two different while loops and I want to add the variable between them outside the loop. Example:

```
while($cash_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($cash_qur))
{
      $a = 500; //suppose I am fetching from database
}

while($card_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($card_qur))
{
    $b = 1000; //suppose I am fetching from database
}

$total = $a+$b;

echo $total;
```

I want to do this thing exactly but I am getting inappropriate results. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
$a = $b = 0; // set to 0 by default
while($cash_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($cash_qur))
{
    $a += 500; //Increment
}

while($card_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($card_qur))
{
    $b += 1000; //Increment
}
$total = $a + $b;
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do like this:

```
$total = 0;
while($cash_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($cash_qur))
{
    ++$total; //Increment
}

while($card_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($card_qur))
{
    ++$total; //Increment
}

echo $total; // this will give you a count of total fetched records
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
$a = 0;
$b = 0;
while($cash_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($cash_qur))
{
      $a = 500; //suppose I am fetching from database
}

while($card_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($card_qur))
{
    $b = 1000; //suppose I am fetching from database
}

$total = $a+$b;

echo $total;
```